# does isolation level have any effect on data modification queries?

Tags: sql, sql-server, transaction-isolation

Based on my reading

Update will acquire `Update(U)` lock on rows it is updating
Insert will acquire either `Update` or `Range` lock
Delete will acquire `Exclusive(X)` lock on rows it is deleting
Truncate will acquire `Exclusive(X)` lock on the table

It seems to me that those operations will auto upgrade the isolation level if the specified level is too low. Which means even if I set it to read uncommitted (dirty read) it will still work fine as if I set it to repeatable read right?

And would it cause any trouble to me if I leave all modification queries to read uncommitted isolation level by default?

Comment: Isolation level != lock type. You're right that update locks will be taken when necessary even if you start out under `READ UNCOMMITTED`, but keep in mind that those queries go through a read phase first to determine what rows to update that will use different locks based on the isolation level. So no, they won't necessarily "work fine" because they can update the wrong rows in the wrong way. You typically want to *increase* the isolation level (and/or use `HOLDLOCK`) to ensure such queries work reliably, rather than go `UNCOMMITTED`.

Comment: DO NOT use read uncommitted for inserts, updates or deletes. It can corrupt your indexes also. Just don't do that. https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: @SeanLange does read uncommitted apply nolock hint implicitly?

Comment: read uncommitted is like applying the nolock hint to the entire batch.

Comment: @SeanLange if you want to write up an answer with some explanation I will accept it.

Comment: @JeroenMostert if you want to write up an answer with some explanation I will accept it.